# Getting active link highlight to align with bottom of navbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css

Summary: I am using jquery to apply an `active` class that adds a `'border-bottom'` to the the link the user is currently viewing. But, the individual links `border-bottom` is displaying a few pixels above the `navbar'`s `border-bottom`.You can see this by expanding the runtime window here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/justinob8/Lopszd1e/4/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
    <a class="navbar-brand left-most-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">LOGO</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link right-link" href="#">Job Search<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link right-link right-most-link" href="{% url 'employer_signup' %}">Post a Job<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>


    </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('li').click(function(){
            $('li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })

    });
```

CSS:

```
nav{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #eeeeee;
}
.right-link{

}
.right-most-link{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.left-most-link{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.active{
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lopszd1e/17/ . try this.

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem change your css file.
Change this:

```
.right-most-link{
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

With this:

```
ul{
   margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add margin-right to ul too,
i don't see `</ul>` in you html code, don't forget it